# MongoDB updateOne vs findAndModify: concurrency

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update, findandmodify

Both UpdateOne and FindAndModify accept query and update part.

Is it possible that another process goes between the execution of the query part and the update part?

Are there differences between UpdateOne and FindAndModify from a performance point of view?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that another process goes between the execution of the
> query part and the update part?

No. [Read here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#concurrency-control)

> Are there differences between UpdateOne and FindAndModify from a
> performance point of view?

No. [Read Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method)